# whats the use of shared mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Consider following example -

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime> 

void wait(int seconds) 
{ 
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds)); 
} 

boost::shared_mutex mutex; 
std::vector<int> random_numbers; 

void fill() 
{ 
  std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0))); 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
  { 
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mutex); 
    random_numbers.push_back(std::rand()); 
    lock.unlock(); 
    wait(1); 
  } 
} 

void print() 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
  { 
    wait(1); 
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mutex); 
    std::cout << random_numbers.back() << std::endl; 
  } 
} 

int sum = 0; 

void count() 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
  { 
    wait(1); 
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mutex); 
    sum += random_numbers.back(); 
  } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
  boost::thread t1(fill); 
  boost::thread t2(print); 
  boost::thread t3(count); 
  t1.join(); 
  t2.join(); 
  t3.join(); 
  std::cout << "Summe: " << sum << std::endl; 
}
```

In the given example, both `print()` and `count()` access random_numbers read-only. While the `print()` function writes the last number of random_numbers to the standard output stream, the `count()` function adds it to the variable sum. Since neither function modifies random_numbers, both can access it at the same time using a non-exclusive lock of type `boost::shared_lock`.

My question is : As the resource is read only why the shared mutex is needed at the first place in count and print function?' Cant we manage without it?

Comment: Well, the vector's also being written to by `fill`...the point is to make sure that the reading doesn't overlap with the writing.

Comment: One producer, many consumers.

Comment: `shared_mutex` was proposed for C++11 but didn't make it into the standard. I'm of the opinion that we could do without it but I imagine something on the lines of `boost::shared_mutex` will make the standard in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> As the resource is read only [...]

No, it is not : the `fill()` method proceed to writes through the following :

```
random_numbers.push_back(std::rand()); // write to random_numbers
```

So the shared mutex really is necessary to synchronize your access to the vector.